# Facebook share does not recognize full URL

Tags: facebook, sharepoint, share, fbconnect, facebook-wall

I'm trying to share a URL like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://exemple.com?page=poster_info&sid=1
```

... but Facebook ignores `&sid=1`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You question is incomprehensible. Please give more details.

Comment: Hm i need when someone press on image to share the page with facebook share.I using this code  http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://fejsbukzabava.hostoi.com?poster_info&sid=".$info['sid']."&t=Fejsbuk-zabava - But it dont want to share that page it sharing  http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://fejsbukzabava.hostoi.com?poster_info how can i fix that?

Comment: your url should not have **$**

Comment: You didn't understand me good.. How can i share this link http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://exemple.com?page=poster_info&sid=1... It show me just where is ?page=poster_info after noting.

Comment: i think you might have to urlencode your url

Comment: I tryed with this http://www.facebook.com/share.php?t=Fejsbuk&u='.urlencode('http://family-gaming.com/fb/index.php?page=poster_info&sid=10'); But it didn't work..

Answer (score 2):

Sharing involves calling this url...

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=MY_LINK
```

use the php function **urlencode()** on **MY_LINK**